# Blanks in path/filename for Dyalog APL ⎕NGET

Tags: whitespace, filenames, dyalog

I am trying to access a native file using the `⎕NGET` system function on a Ubuntu Unix system.

This works fine as long as the path/filename string does not contain blanks. If the path contains blanks the file is not recognized.

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: ⎕SH'echo hello world >my\ file.txt'
      ⎕←⊃⎕NGET'my file.txt'
hello world

this works fine, however: 

⎕SH 'echo hello world > /home/adrian/.wine/drive_c/users/adrian/Application\ Data/Suuntolink/test.txt'
      ⎕←⊃⎕NGET'/home/adrian/.wine/drive_c/users/adrian/Application\ Data/Suuntolink/test.txt'
FILE NAME ERROR: /home/adrian/.wine/drive_c/users/adrian/Application\ Data/Suunt
olink/test.txt: Unable to open file ("No such file or directory")
      ⎕←⊃⎕NGET'/home/adrian/.wine/drive_c/users/adrian/Application\ Data/Suunto
      link/test.txt'
         ∧what is going on

Comment: That's exactly the same situation; do not escape spaces in the argument to `⎕NGET`. You kept ``\`` in `Application\ Data` (and also inserted a space in `Suunto link`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly goes wrong, but note that spaces should not be escaped in the argument to `⎕NGET`:

```
      ⎕SH'echo hello world > my\ file.txt'
      ⎕←⊃⎕NGET'my file.txt'
hello world
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1GAP9dTkjHyFjNScnHyF8vyinBQFO4XcyhiFtMycVL2SihJ1LqCyR20THnU1Axl@7q4h6rmVCNn//wE)

Comment: Adam, many thanks. Problem solved. I had to take out quotes from the text string that I saved as a variable for the native file name.